# change value of schedule during run time

Tags: anylogic

I have a schedule that indicates the opening time of a service!
it's a schedule of intervals, so from 8:00 to 1:00 it's ON from 1:00 to 2:00 it's OFF, from 2:00 to 6:00 it's ON again and from 6:00 to 8:00 it's OFF.
Is it possible to change dynamically the opening times, so to vary these intervals through some parameters?

Answer (score 0):

If there are only 2 or 3 alternative schedules then it is worth defining them explicitly as separate objects and using them this way.

Another option: **Schedule** objects have a concept of *Exceptions* - this is where it is possible to change the *value* (in this case ON instead of OFF) of the schedule for a particular period of time. These can be done via interface or programmatically using `addException()` method. Please see more [here](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/data/exceptions.html).

Furthermore, it is possible to create schedules programmatically. There is actually an example model in AnyLogic that shows how to do it. Please see  "Schedule created programmatically" in your "AnyLogic => Help => Example Models => How to models".

Unfortunately, programmatically created schedules lack `Action` property, however this can be achieved by having an **Event** object with a conditional trigger which triggers when `schedule.getValue()` returns true.

Comment: But, if the alternative schedules are more than 2 or 3? I tried to create a dynamic schedule with a variable, but by doing so I lose the "action" field that I have in the schedules

Comment: Can you elaborate on the type of changes you want to do to a schedule? and how many variations there will be?

Comment: I would like that before the start of the simulation it would be possible to choose through some buttons or sliders the opening hours of the service! Then to use the values in output of the buttons/slider like parameters for the schedules. timetables that can be also H24 of opening

Comment: Ok, I have clarified my answer above.